# Error when send mail in java using javamail?

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

i want to use javamail so i test this code

```
public class Test_Mail {
public static void main(String [] args)
 {    
 String to="xyz@gmail.com";//change accordingly  

//Get the session object  
Properties props = new Properties();  
props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");  
props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");  
props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",  
        "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");  
props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");  
props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");  

Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,  
new javax.mail.Authenticator() {  
protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {  
return new PasswordAuthentication("abc@gmail.com","*****");  
 }  
});  

//compose message  
try {  
MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);  
message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("abc@gmail.com"));//change accordingly  
message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,new InternetAddress(to));  
message.setSubject("Hello");  
message.setText("Testing.......");  

//send message  
Transport.send(message);  

System.out.println("message sent successfully");  

} catch (MessagingException e) {throw new RuntimeException(e);}  

}  
}
```

but i have this error:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 534-5.7.14  Please log in via your web browser and
534-5.7.14 then try again.
534-5.7.14 Learn more at
534 5.7.14 https://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=78754 gj16sm129363wic.24 - gsmtp

i tried many changes but it's the same error.

Comment: Nothing to do with your Java code, google isn't allowing you to send the mail.

Comment: do you mean thet google is the problem ? why ?

Comment: Did you follow the link in the error message?  Did you login using your web browser?  Did you configure your account to allow access by less secure apps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because Google is such a large target for SPAM they have policies and practices in place to try and prevent as much SPAM as possible.  It appears that your account may have been flagged by one of these policies and requires some manual intervention to get it working again.